# NSKeyedUnarchiver read nil for some of the attributes though data is present in the file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please advise for the below two issues.

1. I am using the below command to read the contents of a file.But some of the data is coming as nil even though the data is present in the file.Please advise how to unarchive the plist file.

   ```
   Dealer *dealer=[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/Users/Documents/dealer.plist"] retain];
   ```
2. For the line:

   ```
   @property NSDecimalNumber *miles
   ```

   i am writing like

   ```
   self.miles = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"miles"]
   ```

   in the `initWithCoder` method

   and

   ```
   [aCoder encodeObject:_miles forKey:@"miles"]
   ```

   in the `encodeWithCoder` method.

But the data is not saved in the plist file. Please advise.

Comment: As an aside, the absence of the `retain` qualifier for the declaration of your `NSDecimalNumber` is worrying. You really should include a proper qualifier so that the synthesized accessor methods do the proper memory management for you. If you do a static analysis ("Analyze" in Xcode's "Product" menu), it will warn you of these sorts of problems. Or better, use ARC, which makes your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

- You shouldn't use a hard coded path like that. You should use a path inside the documents, cache, or temp folder of the app.
- Did you check the return code of `archiveRootObject`? Was it successful?

But there's nothing wrong with the `encodeObject:forKey:` and `decodeObjectForKey:` calls. The following code worked fine for me. If the problem is not the path, then the issue rests elsewhere. If you're still having a problem, then edit your question to include [the smallest-possible, yet complete and stand-alone example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a MCVE) you describe.

---

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber *miles;  // use `strong` if using ARC
@end

@implementation MyObject

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.miles = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"miles"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:_miles forKey:@"miles"];
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MyObject %p; miles=%@>", self, self.miles];
}

// if ARC, remove this `dealloc` method

- (void)dealloc {
    [_miles release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:false error:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

    MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    object.miles = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:42 exponent:0 isNegative:false];

    BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:object toFile:fileURL.path];
    NSLog(@"%@", success ? @"success" : @"failure");

    MyObject *object2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fileURL.path];
    NSLog(@"%@", object2);

    [object release];  // not needed if using ARC
}

@end
```